# How to add Ms-Access database column in any String [] in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am a newbie to C#.

I want to add my one of database's column in `string[]` but fail to do so. I have created `string[]` with name "Items" and also create a control with name autocompletemenu1. Now when I type `autocompetemenu1.Items = Database Column` then the contents of database column should be filled in ITEM `string[]`. I have tried but it is not working so I just mention some name in it and it is working but it is not taking database column. Don't know why! Please help

Thank you in advance.

This is the method ITEM I am using to take collections. Way to write is

```
autocompleteMenu1.Items = Database column
```

My code:

```
[DefaultValue(null)]
public string[] Items
{
    get
    {
        if (sourceItems == null)
            return null;

        var list = new List<string>();

        foreach (AutocompleteItem item in sourceItems)
            list.Add(item.ToString());

        return list.ToArray();
    }
    set { SetAutocompleteItems(value); 
}
```

Here is the assignment of String [] to Item method but I want to add database column instead of string [] ... how can I do this...?

```
 this.autocompleteMenu1.Items = new string [] 
        {

            "Jamal",
            "Javed",
            "Jameel",
            "James",
            "Jamshed",
            "abc",
            "abcd",
            "Ahmed",
        };
```

Comment: update question with your code

Comment: You would help us a lot if you could provide the relevant lines of your code that aren't working.